# fedora: su: authentication failure after libz.so.1 link removed

Tags: operating-system, root, sudo, fedora, zlib

In fedora 36, after remove the link of libz.so.1 in /user/lib64/, I cannot su or sudo, cannot poweroff normally even. Is there any solution?

```
$su
su: Authentication failure
$sudo ln -s libz.so.1.2.11 libz.so.1
sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's the problem of this lib. All I have to do is to insert a live USB, and boot from it then make a link to libz.so.1.xx.